# Prevent axios get request outside component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I made my first component with Vue, it's adding data to database, but it also getting datas from get axios. My questions is, how to secure axios get request? Because if any user go to http://localhost/get-data/ he will get JSON output with data on computer screen. How to prevent that?

I'm using Laravel for backend and Vue for frontend

Answer (score 0):

you should use api authentication, 
you have two way:

1. use [laravel api-authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication) ( add api-key field in your user table and send it for any request )
2. use [laravel passport](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport) ( recommended )

Comment: But I will have to change method of login / register Users? I want to stay on web auth login/register or can I use both?

Comment: If you use blade or you have  web urls witch want authorize you should use both of them but if you want write SPA , you can use api auth only . Yes you need change methods , or write custom methods